# Early exit for Rx.Observable.retryWhen/timer

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Given **`A`** async task that went wrong and is being **`R`** recovered. When recovery begins I need **to post seconds remaining to recover** and to have option **for early exit of `T`** timer if desired.

Basically, I want to have a functionality similar to: 
*Reconnect in **`N`** s*, **reconnect now**?

```
// S - instance scope

let ws = Rx.Observable.create((obs: Rx.Observer<{}>) => {
  // A - async that may fail
  obs.error("error");
}).retryWhen((errors: Rx.Observable<{}>) => {
  // R - progress of recovery
  return Rx.Observable.timer(5000); // T timer
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okaaay, I finally figured it out. Just posting for reference

[run jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dacuva/edit?js,console)

```
console.clear();

let recoveryDelay = new Rx.Subject(Rx.Observer.create(), Rx.Observable.empty());
let recovery = new Rx.Subject(Rx.Observer.create(), Rx.Observable.empty());

let obs = Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    obs.next(Math.random());
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    obs.error('error');
  }, 3000);
}).retryWhen((error) => {
  return error.flatMap(() => {

    recovery.onNext('wait...');

    return Rx.Observable.create((obs) => {

      let sub = recoveryDelay.subscribe(() => {
        recovery.onNext('force continue');
        obs.next();
        obs.onCompleted();
      });

      let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        obs.next();
        obs.onCompleted();
      }, 20000);

      return () => {
        recovery.onNext('ready');
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        sub.dispose();
      }
    });
  });
});

obs.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

recovery.subscribe(status => console.log('1 status ' + status));
recovery.subscribe(status => console.log('2 status ' + status));

setTimeout(() => {
  recoveryDelay.onNext();
}, 5000);
```